# You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. But Node version is greater than v10

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

Here is my command line I already have node version higher than the specified 10.24.1 but still gives me this error. Not really sure what is the issue here.

I am using nvm.

I also have tried to uninstall and re install npm.

I am using ubuntu
[image: cmd]

Comment: what happens if you run `npm install` without sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `nvm install node` and `nvm use node` then try. I was having this issue because I had my default node version set as 10.13.0 on accident. You can check which node version you are using with `nvm list`.